# Residue at all integers of complex function involving sines

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, residue-calculus

Given $H(z)=\frac{\pi f(z)}{\sin(\pi z)}$, where $f(z)$ is some function which has isolated singularities only at non-integers, is it correct to calculate its residue at $z=k$ (for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$) as follows?

Res$_{z=k}\{f(z)\}=\lim\limits_{z\to k}=\frac{\pi f(z)}{\sin(\pi z)}(z-k)=\frac{f'(z)(z-k)+f(z)}{\cos(\pi z)}=(-1)^k f(k)$.

Just want to make sure I'm not missing something.

Comment: Yes, but since the limit of f(z) for z to k exists, you can use the product rule for limits, and take a factor of f(k) out, that saves you from having to differentiate f(z) when applying L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: @CountIblis sorry can you please show what you mean?

Comment: $$\lim_{z\to k}f(z) g(z) = \lim_{z\to k}f(z) \lim_{z\to k}g(z)$$ if both limits exist.

Comment: But $\lim\limits_{z\to k} \frac{1}{\sin(\pi z)}$ does not exist.

Comment: Yes, but you can choose $g(z) = \frac{z-k}{\sin{\pi z}}$

Comment: And then apply l'Hopital's rule anyway. But yes, that would simplify it in some sense.